# Grafana charts grouped by day or month?

Tags: postgresql, grafana, dashboard

I am stuck with the graph due to not being able to group the graphs by date. I am using dates and counters to make my queries visual, the problem is that adding them to grafana looks like this.

My problem:

[image]

Query:

```
select 
   to_char(created,'yyyy-mm-dd') as "time", count(created) as created
from
   [table]
group by
   to_char(created,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

I use a similar query for each graph, coming to be visualized as My problem image.

[image]

How can I make it look like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some `$__timeGroup*/$__unixEpochGroup*` macro (it depends on the column `created` type) - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/#macros. Example:

```
SELECT
  $__unixEpochGroupAlias(created, 30d),
  count(*) AS "count"
FROM $table
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(created)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Eventually you need to write SQL on your own to group by calendar month.

Comment: thank you very much, i customized it and it worked for me.

Comment: Although the problem persists, when a row from another query is in the same month, they occupy the same place.

Comment: Output is time series and all series have the same time, so they will be displayed on the same place, when X-axe is the time. You can swith X-axe to series, but expect many problems - another SQL query, not sorting because time must string in this case, ...

Comment: ouh ok, but is it possible to group by month the data that have the same date but different value? that they are separated and not one on top of the other?